# Drupal 7 использование нескольких тем

Tags: drupal

Создал II тему в друпал
Задача была - на отдельной странице выводить форму для iframe - следовательно стилей по минимум, подгружаемых файлов по минимуму.
сделал hook_menu() c этой страницей
захотел чтобы в html не кидались css и js

в этом же модуле написал
hook_js_alter(&$javascript) и hook_css_alter(&$css) и те ссылки, которые они принимают отредактировал - обрезал массивы и оставил только нужные подключения

все работает как надо - заходим на страницу - видим те подключения, которые нужны, но при заходе на страницы с другой темой - друпал и там начал обрезать css и js.

В итоге перенес тело хуков (hook_js_alter(&$javascript) и hook_css_alter(&$css) )в функцию 'page callback', которая отрабатывает только на этой странице

Сбросил кеш - на странице с новой темой показываются подключенные файлы css и js - те которые нужны, сколько бы раз не обновлял, перехожу на страницу с другой темой - все отлично - страница грузится первый раз долго - в html вижу все друпаловские дефолтные подключения. Перехожу обратно на тему с формой - обновляю - подгружаются (видимо) закешированные подключаемые css и js.

Я не понимаю как средствами друпала - сказать программе - на этой странице - используй эти подключения js файлов, а на другой не используй свои дефолтные подключения css и js и подключения всех остальных модулей

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример:

```
function MYTHEME_js_alter(&$javascript) {
  if (current_path() == 'your_path') {
    unset($javascript['path/to/script.js']);
  }
}
```

При частом исользовании формы могут быть проблемы с объемом таблицы cache_form в базе данных. Она не чиститься кнопкой с админки Clear_all_cache,поэтому ее надо чистить по крону вручну, и самому выбирать какие данные с этой таблицы удалить, а какие оставить.

Comment: Это просто шикарное решение - MYTHEME - подтолкнуло меня переместить функции в стандартный друпаловский файл функций тем template.php - создал его. И даже не понадобилось использовать if (current_path() == 'your_path'). Вы решили еще одну проблему!

Comment: Теперь II шаблон использует только нужные подключаемые файлы, старый шаблон использует подключаемые файлы всех модулей - как и было задумано